# Why does this Graph implementation use array for visited state?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, graph

This implementation from Geeks for Geeks strangely utilize array to implement bfs.

Link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementation-graph-javascript/

In the step "add the starting node to the queue", it even assigns "startingNode" as an index of the "visited" array, which sounds very off(it would make a bit more sense if it used object as the type). I was wondering if they incorrectly wrote this or if not, I'd like someone more experienced to explain this to me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traversal needs an efficient way to lookup a particular node in the visited set. That can be done efficiently with an array lookup such as `if (!visited[neigh])`. Another option would be using a string key and an object to represent the visited set, but it would likely be less efficient. Referring to the nodes as objects only would complicate things since there would be no natural key one could use to determine membership in the visited set.

Comment: Is it a good practice to use index value as (or the thing that goes into that bracket) something other than a number? I thought a good alternative would be Map object, but the author's choice of Array got me confused a bit here. I appreciate your help!

Comment: You could certainly use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) object, which was recently introduced in ES2015, and would be a more modern style of JS. In terms of raw performance though, an array would still win out - fewer objects to allocate, faster lookups.